# Stream media file using WebRTC

Tags: javascript, html, webrtc

Here is my use case: Alice has a cool new media track that she wants Bob to listen in to. She selects the media file in her browser and the media file starts playing instantly in Bob's browser.

I'm not even sure if this is possible to build using WebRTC API right now. All examples I can find use streams obtained via getUserMedia() but this is what I have:

```
var context = new AudioContext();
var pc = new RTCPeerConnection(pc_config);

function handleFileSelect(event) {
    var file = event.target.files[0];

    if (file) {
        if (file.type.match('audio*')) {
            console.log(file.name);
            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = (function(readEvent) {
                context.decodeAudioData(readEvent.target.result, function(buffer) {
                    var source = context.createBufferSource();
                    var destination = context.createMediaStreamDestination();
                    source.buffer = buffer;
                    source.start(0);
                    source.connect(destination);
                    pc.addStream(destination.stream);
                    pc.createOffer(setLocalAndSendMessage);
                });
            });

            reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
        }
    }
}
```

On the receiving side I have the following:

```
function gotRemoteStream(event) {
    var mediaStreamSource = context.createMediaStreamSource(event.stream);
    mediaStreamSource.connect(context.destination);
}
```

This code does not make the media (music) play on the receiving side. <strike>I do however receive an *ended* event right after the WebRTC handshake is done and the *gotRemoteStream* function was called.</strike> The *gotRemoteStream* function gets called the media does not start playing.

On Alice's side the magic is suppose to happen in the line that says *source.connect(destination)*. When I replace that line with *source.connect(context.destination)* the media start playing correctly through Alice's speakers.

On Bob's side a media stream source is created based upon Alice's stream. However when the local speaker are connected using *mediaStreamSource.connect(context.destination)* the music doesn't start playing through the speakers.

Off course I could always send the media file through a DataChannel but where is the fun in that...

Any clues on what is wrong with my code or some ideas on how to achieve my use case would be greatly appreciated!

I'm using the latest and greatest Chrome Canary.

Thanks.

Comment: Due to an error in my code the received stream on Bob's side was ended because the SDP answer on Alice's side was not handeld correctly. After fixing the issue the media still does not play but the example behaves differently. I updated the question accordingly.

Comment: it might be unrelated (I have no experience with webRTC) but could https://github.com/wearefractal/holla help you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to play the audio using the *Audio* element like this:

```
function gotRemoteStream(event) {
    var player = new Audio();
    attachMediaStream(player, event.stream);
    player.play();
}
```

Playing back the audio via the WebAudio API it not working (yet) for me.

Answer (score 1):

Note sure about Chrome; sounds like a bug.

try it on Firefox (nightly I suggest); we have WebAudio support there though I don't know all the details about what's supported currently.

Also, on Firefox at least we have stream = media_element.captureStreamUntilEnded(); we use it in some of our tests in dom/media/tests/mochitests I believe.  This lets you take any audio or video element and capture the output as a mediastream.

Edit: see below; both Chrome and Firefox have misses in combining WebAudio with WebRTC PeerConnections, but in different places.  Mozilla hopes to fix the last bug there very soon.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I tried but currently FirefoxNightly does not implement _MediaContext.createMediaStreamSource_ yet.

Comment: It does a chrome bug: webaudio does not support remote stream. here: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?can=2&q=121673&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Iteration%20ReleaseBlock%20Cr%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified&groupby=&sort=&id=121673

Comment: Yes, right now Chrome supports WebAudio on PeerConnection inputs, but not outputs (see the bug @Imskull linked to).  Firefox supports WebAudio on PeerConnection outputs, but not on inputs.  One small issue remains; with that fixed we'll support that as well.  Probably in 39, maybe 38, *maybe* 37 if it's trivial.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the page [MediaStream Integration](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/audio/raw-file/tip/webaudio/webrtc-integration.html). It illustrates WebRTC integration with the Web Audio API. In particular this example is relevant for your question:

> 5. Capture microphone input, visualize it, mix in another audio track and stream the result to a peer

```
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
<audio src="back.webm" id="back"></audio>
<script>
    navigator.getUserMedia('audio', gotAudio);
    var streamRecorder;
    function gotAudio(stream) {
        var microphone = context.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
        var backgroundMusic = context.createMediaElementSource(document.getElementById("back"));
        var analyser = context.createAnalyser();
        var mixedOutput = context.createMediaStreamDestination();
        microphone.connect(analyser);
        analyser.connect(mixedOutput);
        backgroundMusic.connect(mixedOutput);
        requestAnimationFrame(drawAnimation);

        peerConnection.addStream(mixedOutput.stream);
    }
</script>
```

I fear, however, that this is only a proposal currently.

Comment: Unfortunately, it won't work in Chrome 59. When you do `peerConnection.addStream(mixedOutput.stream)`, you get the error: `Failed to execute 'addStream' on 'RTCPeerConnection': parameter 1 is not of type 'MediaStream'.`

Comment: By the way, same error in Firefox 53: `TypeError: Argument 1 of RTCPeerConnection.addStream does not implement interface MediaStream.`